# How to save .pfx certificate into a Sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, certificate, pfx

I am trying to save .pfx file in sqlite db and install it after getting its info from DB itself, not directly from the file. I am storing its Byte array in BLOB column and other info in respective to their type in DB, but it fails to install when I get it through sql Query.

**Getting Byte Array:**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(certificateFile));

        try {
            IOUtils.copyStream(reader, baos);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
            baos.close();
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
```

Please suggest any solution regarding this. I searched for the solution and found that I have to store .pem and .cer file separately after extracting .pfx file, but unable to find how? How could I save those info programmatically?.

Comment: "...and install it ..." what do you mean by "install it"?

Comment: Means Load certificate into the device, so that it will show in the User Credentials section of the Settings Screen.